# Issue with using swagger in webapplication

Tags: java, swagger

I am using swagger in my web application and when I deploy the application, I am getting the below error in the logs

> Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLFactory' (current
>   frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to
>   'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory'

My pom.xml have the below dependencies

```
<!-- swagger -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

please help me

Comment: You must share the stacktrace

Comment: And the line of assignment will be helpful too.

Comment: I hope you tried adding dependency for YAMLFactory.

Comment: @RohitVerma if you are talking about the jar jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.8.5.jar its coming automatically with the other dependencies

Comment: i am facing this error also